# react-router best way to handle session timeout

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am working on a react SPA. Every time this webApp request data from server by `Ajax`, the server checks if the session is timeout, if it does, sever return errorCode `USER_NOT_LOGGED_IN` to webApp. when webApp get this errorCode, it should jump to `login` page.

I want to implement this logic in Http service so that I can "write once".

httpsService:

```
axios(httpOptions).then(response => {
        let data = response.data
        if (data) {
          switch (data.code) {
            case 'OK':
              resolve(data.data)
              break

            case 'USER_NOT_LOGGED_IN':
            case 'CSRF_FAILED':
              // goto login
              break

            .......
```

components:

```
export default class Home extends Component {

  test = () => {
    post('test/', {
      cellphone: '100001',
      password: '6666666'
    }).then(data => {
      console.log('ok', data)
    }, error => {
      console.log('error', error)
    })
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
        Home
        <button onClick={this.test}>testHttp</button>
      </div>
  }
}
```

Now the question is how can I change the router state in `httpsService`. Should I do this in React?

Comment: are you using `react-router`, `redux` or `react-router-redux`?

Comment: I am using Mobx

Comment: @VF_ , you have solution with redux and react-router-redux?